# Any idea why my DataGrid is not loading data from datareader?

Tags: vb.net

I'm so wondering why my code not work now before its run but now just nothing to show like Exit sub..

```
Try
    Dim z As Integer = 0

    Dim dr3 As MySqlDataReader

    Dim qryPO3 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT product_ID, Quantity, Unit_Cost FROM PO_Details WHERE PO_ID = " & PO_ID & "", conn)

    dr3 = qryPO3.ExecuteReader()

    While dr3.Read()
        dtItem.Rows.Add()

        dtItem.Item(0, z).Value = dr3("Product_ID")
        dtItem.Item(5, z).Value = dr3("Quantity")
        dtItem.Item(7, z).Value = dr3("Unit_Cost")
        dtItem.Item(8, z).Value = dr3("Unit_Cost") * dr3("Quantity")

        z = z + 1

    End While

    dr3.Close()
    dr3.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex).ToString()
End Try
```

Please I'm stuck with this stuff

Thanks and appreciated.

Comment: a) use SQL parameters rather than gluing little bits of string together b) check that there is matching data c) it would be easier to fill a datatable and bind it rather than poking untyped values into each cell.

Comment: You should always close and dispose of your data connections as soon as you execute your query.  Step through your code with the debugger to see what's happening.  Try to avoid just column index numbers.  You might insert a new column in a future update and then you would have to readjust all those indexes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure `DataGrid.Item()` is `(row, column)` and it looks like you are doing `(column, row)`. So in your `While` loop try this:

```
    dtItem.Item(z, 0).Value = dr3("Product_ID")
    dtItem.Item(z, 5).Value = dr3("Quantity")
    dtItem.Item(z, 7).Value = dr3("Unit_Cost")
    dtItem.Item(z, 8).Value = dr3("Unit_Cost") * dr3("Quantity")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys ... I was missing that I was coded the rowadded even, the code is perfectly executed after I deleted the code in the said e